# [Vue warn]: Error compiling template (when im try to show blade command as string)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, laravel-blade

i am using `laravel6` and `vuejs` to make a tutorial website (laravel tutorial). i have my tutorials in my DB and some of my tutorials contains Blade Commands such as `@foreach` and something else.

now i have vue template error when i want to show body of my tutorial by this command in blade:

```
{!! $article->body !!}
```

help please. thank you

Comment: what is the vue template warning?

Answer (score 0):

if the article is a vue variable, Use this command:

```
{{ article.body }}
```

But if it's a variable that is sent from a controller to a blade, use this command:

```
{{ $article->body }}
```